# How to make a local variable work inside other functions (Python)

Tags: python

I am a beginner at python and currently working on a project.  When I try to run this code, it keeps telling me that random_Number and users_Guess is not defined.

```
#Impots the random module
import random


#Calls all functions
def main():
    generateNumber()
    inputUsersGuess()
    displayAnswer()

#Generates the random number
def generateNumber():
    random_Number=random.randint(1,100)
    return random_Number


#Takes the users guess
def inputUsersGuess():
    users_Guess=int(input('I am thinking of a number. What is the number? '))
    return users_Guess

#Compares the users guess with the number generated
def displayAnswer():
    if random_Number==users_Guess:
        print('You guessed correctly!')
    else:
        print('Sorry, your guess is incorrect. I was thinking of',random_Number)

#Calls the main function
main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to make a local variable available in other functions. The whole purpose of dividing your program into different functions is to isolate one function from the internals of another function.

Instead, *pass* the values between the functions that need them. First, have `main()` actually pick up the numbers the functions are returning. As your code stands it is throwing the returned values away.

```
def main():
    random_number = generateNumber()
    guess = inputUsersGuess()
    displayAnswer(random_number, guess)
```

Here I have changed the signature of the function `displayAnswer()` to accept the two returned values passed in from `main()`. So that needs to be reflected in the function definition:

```
def displayAnswer(random_Number,users_Guess):
    if random_Number==users_Guess:
        print('You guessed correctly!')
    else:
        print('Sorry, your guess is incorrect. I was thinking of',random_Number)
```

Comment: Thank you so much I understand what I need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use global variables if you can help it. Return values from your functions and then pass them to the other functions that need them

```
import random


def main():
    number = generate_number()
    users_guess = input_users_guess()
    display_answer(number, users_guess)


def generate_number():
    return random.randint(1,100)


def input_users_guess():
    return int(input('I am thinking of a number. What is the number? '))


def display_answer(number, users_guess):
    if number == users_guess:
        print('You guessed correctly!')
    else:
        print('Sorry, your guess is incorrect. I was thinking of', number)

main()
```